# Doing foreach through an array how to get the element index in JavaSecript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Needless to say the following code prints 110 and 115 to the console:

```
var a = new Array();

a[10] = 110;
a[15] = 115;

a.forEach(function(entry) {
    console.log(entry);
});
```

But what if I need the index too? The function I am writing needs to process an array without knowing what elements are defined, the indices of defined elements are themselves valuable information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument passed to your anonymous function is an index

```
a.forEach(function(entry, index) {
    console.log(entry);
});
```

References:

- [Array.prototype.forEach() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)